# Eloquent Relationship returns multiple arrays

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have set up a relationship between 2 models Route and Booking

a Route has many bookings 
a Booking belongs too a route

Route Model:

```
//
public function books()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Booking::class);
}
```

Booking Model

```
public function route()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Route::class);
}
```

Now in my controller i try to access the route a particular booking belongs to

```
public function bookFeed(Request $request, Booking $booking)
{
    $bookR = $booking->with('route')->get();

    dd($bookR);
}
```

or even this

```
$bookR = $bookRef->route()->get();

dd($bookR);
```

and i get a collection with multiple Route arrays, now to access a value i have to do

```
$bookR[0]->value
```

why is this so, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: what is the result of dd($booking->exists);

Comment: the result is true

Comment: Try `$booking->load('route');` instead of `$booking->with('route')->get()` This will load the related route of your booking. Your code starts a new query when using like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `first()` in your query

```
$bookR = $booking->route()->first();
```

or

```
$bookR = $booking->route
```

Comment: you were using `->get()` which generates collection

Comment: what if i wanted to use say the id of the retrieved route to query the bookings table again, will i write another query or there's an efficient way to do this?

Comment: If you check your query logs, this solution executes multiple select queries in database. However this is unnecessary. You already have the booking object. The only thing you need to do is to load the relation instead of querying the booking itself.

Comment: @dapo you already have booking object, you don't need to bother again

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public function bookFeed(Request $request, Booking $booking)
{
    $booking->load('route');

    dd($booking); // or $booking->route now.
}
```